# Mocking with @mock is coming as null

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to run a junit test like this , using mockito and injecting dependancies in the PageBuilderService service class .

```
  @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
  @ActiveProfiles(profiles = "staging")
  @ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class , classes = {ContentProperties.class , MasterPropertiesFactory.class })
  class PageBuilderServiceTest {



      @Mock
      public CService cs;

      @Mock
      private RService rs;

      @InjectMocks
      PageBuilderService pageBuilderService  ;




      @ParameterizedTest
      @EnumSource(HompageEnum.class)
      @DisplayName("Testing doIt wsith EnumSource")
      public void checkRowposition(HompageEnum homepageEnum) {

          Mockito.when(contentProperties.getPageFolder(anyString())).thenReturn("http://google.com");


      }

  }
```

My Main class is

```
    @Service("pgService")
    public class PageBuilderService {


        @Autowired
        private RService rs;

        @Autowired
        public CService cs;



        public Queue<String> getPaginatedContent(HomepageRequest homepageRequest) {

            Queue<String> staticContent = getStaticContent(homepageRequest.getUrl());

            return staticContent
        }



        public Queue<String> getStaticContent(String url) {

            Queue<String> files = new LinkedList<>();

            String dir = contentProperties.getPageFolder(url);


            return null;
        }


    }
```

When we do ContentProperties content = mock(ContentProperties.class) , it works fine but contentProperties is coming as null when i use mock Annotation .

Comment: Please append your whole class, we can't even see your imports.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what is `contentProperties` - you don't inject it in the test, but here is one thing that is clearly wrong:

If you want to start spring you have to run it with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class` / `SpringRunner.class` and not with mockito runner.

Without spring runner, there is no point in specifying:

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "staging")
  @ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class , classes = {ContentProperties.class , MasterPropertiesFactory.class })
```

Other than that, please check that `@Mock public CService cs;` and other fields annotated with `@Mock` do have value (its basically what Mockito runner is supposed to do, so unless something is missing here, there is no difference between other mocks and `contentProperties`)